# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios

```
var audioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vellipomaakey", ofType: "mp3")!).
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 2):

Did you see it in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section? If not, press on `+` sign to add that mp3 file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping your optional, consider the following:

```
if let res = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vellipomaakey", ofType: "mp3") {
    var audioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:res)
}
```

This will most likely take away your run time error but it won't solve your issue. The problem here is that the resource you are trying to load is not being found, so `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "vellipomaakey, ofType: "mp3")` is returning `nil`.